# Android 6 AudioManager returns wrong RingerMode

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

On Android 6 this issue occurred and working fine with Android 7,8,9,10, 10+.

While using the AudioManager to get the Phone ringer mode, the value return for the mute is wrong.

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    switch (am.getRingerMode()) {
     case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
        Log.i("MyApp","Silent mode");
        break;
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
       Log.i("MyApp","Vibrate mode");
       break;
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
       Log.i("MyApp","Normal mode");
       break;
}
```

For mode set to AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT, it returns the mode AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE, i.e the int value is 1 and not 0.

Value for other ringer profile is returned correctly.

How to get correct silent mode?

Comment: "For mode set to AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT" means you set by code or manual by your hand?

Comment: Didn't get your point? I am using the device Ringer profile like Mute, Sound, Vibrate and not through any code.